# Add two related conditions in if / PHP

Tags: php

I would like to find a way to add a condition in my "if" related to a first condition. Is there a way translating "FOLLOW BY" in php?

My start script with one condition:

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if ($begin == false && $value == 'T') {
 ...
 }}
```

My final script with two conditions related :

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if ($begin == false && $value == 'T' FOLLOW BY $value == 'D') {
 ...
 }}
```

Array for example :

```
 Word => S
 Word => H 
 Word => T //related with D
 Word => D //related with T
 Word => Q
```

Comment: Show us example array please.

Comment: What is follow by supposed to be?  A value of TD or two separate values of T and D?

Comment: @u_mulder it is done

Comment: @Devon There are two separate values

Comment: I personally think this is a flawed structure.  Why should one value care about the next or previous values in the array?   If you provided context, I guarantee there is a fundamental problem somewhere.

Comment: @Devon It is important for me to have these two values ​​in a table simply to make a transition of several sentences.

Comment: How can all the elements of the array have the same key `Word`?

Comment: @Barmar, I guess it was supposed to be `Word 1`, `Word 2` etc...

Answer (score 1):

In case your `$array` is numeric, you can check the value of `$array[$key+1]`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($begin == false && $value == 'T' && array_key_exists($key+1, $array) && $array[$key+1] == 'D') {
        ...
    }
}
```

> Note that I also insert in the code a check if the **next** key exists in your array (otherwise you will have a problem in the last loop)

If your `$array` is associative array it's a bit harder. We need to save the `keys` in a temp array so we can check their position:

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $key_pos = array_search($key, $array_keys);
    if ($begin == false && $value == 'T' && array_key_exists($key_pos+1, $array_keys) && $array[array_keys[$key_pos+1]] == 'D') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, unfortunately the keys in my case are words and not numbers.

Comment: @user7358912 did you check the update in my answer regarding the assoc arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer fit your case, but a simpler solution would be to just implode the array and perform a simple text search.